# Regex to match if statements in code

Tags: regex, string-matching

I need to find if statements(Java Style) in any given file using regex. And then I need to check for clauses, that is -

`if(a < b)` has 1 clause

`if(a || b)` has 2 clauses

`if(a || b && c)` has 3 clauses

A clause is a expression that does not contain any logical operators. The expression inside the if statement is a single clause unless it is separated by logical operators.

What I want to know is how to find write the regex for the clauses. Because if say -

`[i][f][ ][(][A-Za-z!][)]` will give me a error

I don't know how to search for any words, the above regex is searching for a single letter or exclamation mark.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Square brackets are used to create character sets, which will match one of the characters it contains. A character set that contains only one character is identical to just writing those characters normally (with some notable exceptions. `[i][f]` for example, is the same pattern as `if`.

Comment: That aside, what is the context of this issue? Are you incorporating this regex pattern into code? Using a text editor? What do you want to have it return? A list of all the clauses? A count of them?

Comment: Your regex can be easily written as:   if\s?\([A-Za-z!]\)

Comment: @CAustin I need to count the number of if with 1 clause, number of if with 2 clauses etc. I just need a number I am writing the regex in a text editor. I a huge program in Notepad++ and I want to use regex to find the count because this program has 302 if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Regex itself won't return a count for you, but since you're using Notepad++, the search function will let you know how many matches are found. The only problem will be that you'll need to feed it a separate pattern for each number of clauses you want to find.

To search for if statements that contain one clause:

`if\([^|&\n]*?\)`

https://regex101.com/r/ZGopJH/1

Two clauses:

`if\(([^|&\n]*? (?:\|\||&&) [^|&\n]*?)\)`

https://regex101.com/r/EcYizT/3

Three clauses:

`if\(([^|&\n]*? (?:\|\||&&) [^|&\n]*?){2}\)`

https://regex101.com/r/EcYizT/4

For more than three, just increase the quantifier at the end of the pattern accordingly (referring to the `{2}` above; change it to n - 1 where n is the number of clauses you're looking for).

Note that this pattern makes the assumption that clauses will never contain single instances of `|` or `&`. If accounting for those characters is a requirement, the pattern will need to be much more complicated.